# How to invoke WL.client.init API for MFP v8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I upgrade my cordova app to MFP v8 latest iFIx (8.0.0.00-20170220-1900) and now I am not able to connect to MFP from my cordova app.

In Xcode , I see the error

```
WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the 
webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate: <Illigal API call> IBM

MobileFirst Platform framework is not initialized. [WL mainHtmlFilePath] 

API should be used after the successful callback of the 
[WL initWithDelegate:] 
API. This is to ensure that IBM MobileFirst Platform framework 
initialization is complete and web resources are ready to be used.
```

This is my snippet of the call

```
try {
  WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('MFP: "WL" init error - ' + err);
  initFailure(err);
}
```

---

```
var wlInitOptions = {
timeout: 1000,
onConnectionFailure: initFailure,
onFailure: initFailure,
onSuccess: function () {
    console.log('MFP: Loaded');
    initDeferred.resolve();         
    connectToMobileFirst();
 }
};
```

The onSuccess or Failure method is never called.

Thanks for your help

Comment: was this working before the update?

Comment: Yes  Vivin. it was working before I upgrade to the latest iFix

Comment: What is the exact server version ?If it is older than your client , you have to upgrade the server

Comment: The server version is 8.0.0.00-20170220-1900 which is latest version for MFP. I got this information by selecting 'about' from the MFP operation console and it was the version of the iFix.

Comment: Is there anything seen in the client side logs? Do you see network traffic going to the server - use a tool such as Wireshark to see if it is reaching the server and if server is responding